# Add multiple options to an IF(AND...) formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula which begins with an IF statement that checks if the value in cell Calculations!$B$1 is not equal to 2023.

1. If it's not equal, the formula proceeds with further calculations; otherwise, it returns blank. Within this first condition, there are nested IF statements that further refine the count based on the values in cells $B$3 and $B$4.

a) If $B$3 is "All" and $B$4 is "All," it counts rows in the 'TAS' worksheet where specific columns meet certain criteria.

b) If $B$3 is "All," it counts rows based on different criteria.

c) If $B$4 is "All," it counts rows based on different criteria.

d) If neither $B$3 nor $B$4 is "All," it counts rows based on different criteria.

2. If the value in Calculations!$B$1 is 2023, the formula proceeds to another set of nested IF statements, which follow a similar logic as described above, but without considering the value in Calculations!$B$1.

```
=IF(Calculations!$B$1<>2023,
  IF(AND($B$3="All", $B$4="All"),
      COUNTIFS('TAS'!$A$2:$A$999,"="&Calculations!$B$1,
      'TAS'!$L$2:$L$999, Calculations!$H$8,
               'TAS'!$D$2:$D$999, Calculations!$C10),
  IF($B$3="All",
      COUNTIFS('TAS'!$A$2:$A$999,"="&Calculations!$B$1,
      'TAS'!$L$2:$L$999, Calculations!$H$8,
               'TAS'!$D$2:$D$999, Calculations!$C10,
               'TAS'!$K$2:$K$999, "="&Calculations!$B$4),
  IF($B$4="All",
      COUNTIFS('TAS'!$A$2:$A$999,"="&Calculations!$B$1,
      'TAS'!$L$2:$L$999, Calculations!$H$8,
               'TAS'!$D$2:$D$999, Calculations!$C10,
               'TAS'!$H$2:$H$999, "="&Calculations!$B$3),
  COUNTIFS('TAS'!$A$2:$A$999,"="&Calculations!$B$1,
  'TAS'!$L$2:$L$999, Calculations!$H$8,
           'TAS'!$D$2:$D$999, Calculations!$C10,
           'TAS'!$H$2:$H$999, "="&Calculations!$B$3,
           'TAS'!$K$2:$K$999, "="&Calculations!$B$4)))),
  IF(AND($B$3="All", $B$4="All"),
      COUNTIFS('TAS'!$L$2:$L$999, Calculations!$H$8,
               'TAS'!$D$2:$D$999, Calculations!$C10),
  IF($B$3="All",
      COUNTIFS('TAS'!$L$2:$L$999, Calculations!$H$8,
               'TAS'!$D$2:$D$999, Calculations!$C10,
               'TAS'!$K$2:$K$999, "="&Calculations!$B$4),
  IF($B$4="All",
      COUNTIFS('TAS'!$L$2:$L$999, Calculations!$H$8,
               'TAS'!$D$2:$D$999, Calculations!$C10,
               'TAS'!$H$2:$H$999, "="&Calculations!$B$3),
  COUNTIFS('TAS'!$L$2:$L$999, Calculations!$H$8,
           'TAS'!$D$2:$D$999, Calculations!$C10,
           'TAS'!$H$2:$H$999, "="&Calculations!$B$3,
           'TAS'!$K$2:$K$999, "="&Calculations!$B$4)))))
```

It's already quite complicated but I want to add an additional condition, but I think I'm confusing myself with the syntax. I would like to add a third option in addition to $B$3 and $B$4. Right now, these two cells are adjusted based on drop-down menus where you can select either "All" or other options, and hence the formula adjust for when they do not equal "All".

I have added a third cell, $B$2, that can also be "All" or another option can be selected. How would I incorporate it into the above and keep similar calculations? If $B$2 = "All" then much like with the other two, do

```
... COUNTIFS('TAS'!$A$2:$A$999,"="&Calculations!$B$1,
      'TAS'!$L$2:$L$999, Calculations!$H$8,
               'TAS'!$D$2:$D$999, Calculations!$C10)
```

But when $B$2 does NOT equal "All", then adjust it based on adding the following condition (so essentially, match the rows from TAS sheet that equal to whatever the dropdown option in $B$2 is set to):

```
'TAS'!$D$2:$D$999, "="&Calculations!$B$2
```

Comment: You can do yourself a big favor when your logic gets this complicated. Create some intermediate "hidden" columns (could be on the same sheet or another sheet) that calculates and/or collapses some of the logic. This will simplify your formulas and make it much easier to comprehend and to update when something changes.

Comment: Is there a resource you might be able to point me towards on how to set this up or get started with something like this? Very new to excel so hadn't heard of doing something like this and how I would go about approaching it.

Comment: I don't believe your formula functions as you think - from [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NK4N.png) analysis you can appreciate that the _VALUE_IF_FALSE_ part cannot execute, since it's initial test is a duplicate of the initial test of the _VALUE_IF_TRUE_ part  - if you resolve this then I think your formula _can_ be streamlined by using `SUMPRODUCT()`

Comment: @A.R. - take a look at [this website](https://exceladept.com/dealing-with-long-formulas-in-excel/) and [this one](https://www.exceltip.com/basic-excel/what-is-an-excel-helper-column.html) to see if those explanations and examples help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably simplify the overall formula with a single COUNTIFS function, using IF logic on the applicable criteria parameters only. For example:

```
=COUNTIFS(
   TAS!$A$2:$A$999, IF(Calculations!$B$1=2023, ">0", Calculations!$B$1),
   TAS!$H$2:$H$999, IF($B$3="All", "*", Calculations!$B$3),
   TAS!$K$2:$K$999, IF($B$4="All", "*", Calculations!$B$4),
   TAS!$L$2:$L$999, Calculations!$H$8,
   TAS!$D$2:$D$999, Calculations!$C10)
```

Without seeing your data, I had to make a few assumptions about sheet "TAS":

1. column A contains positive numeric values only
2. column H contains text values only
3. column K contains text values only
4. there are NO blank cells in any column

The criteria to return "All" records from a column will depend on the data type. In general, the following will work:

| Data Type | "ALL" Criteria | Used to Find |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Text | `"*"` | text containing any number of characters |
| Date | `">0"` | dates greater than zero |
| Number | `">="&MIN(criteria_range)` | numbers greater than or equal to the minimum value in the criteria range |

**NOTE:** The biggest caveat to watch out for with this method is that blank cells will not be included in the results.

**UPDATE:** A simplified method for the criteria to count "All" records in a column, including blank cells, regardless of the data type, is to use the ***not equal to*** operator with "***some random text***". For example, `"<>λ"` can be used to count all values that are not equal to the Greek Small Letter Lambda symbol.

In regards to your question about adding another criteria cell `$B$2`, it's unclear if you are asking about using OR logic or AND logic. In your example snippet you've referenced column D again `'TAS'!$D$2:$D$999, "="&Calculations!$B$2` which is already being compared against the value in `Calculations!$C10`. I'm going to assume this was a typo, and you want to add criteria for another column. For example, if column C contained numeric data, you could use the following additional criteria:

```
=COUNTIFS(
   TAS!$A$2:$A$999, IF(Calculations!$B$1=2023, "<>λ", Calculations!$B$1),
   TAS!$C$2:$C$999, IF($B$2="All", "<>λ", Calculations!$B$2),
   TAS!$H$2:$H$999, IF($B$3="All", "<>λ", Calculations!$B$3),
   TAS!$K$2:$K$999, IF($B$4="All", "<>λ", Calculations!$B$4),
   TAS!$L$2:$L$999, Calculations!$H$8,
   TAS!$D$2:$D$999, Calculations!$C10)
```